# Appending messages in a variable using COALESCE function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my code.

```
DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

;WITH CTE AS (
                    SELECT 'A' AS Message
                UNION
                    SELECT 'B' AS Message
                UNION
                    SELECT 'C' AS Message
                UNION
                    SELECT 'D' AS Message
)

SELECT @msg = COALESCE(ISNULL(@msg,'Attachements') + ', ','') +  Message FROM CTE

SELECT @msg + ' are missing.'
```

It is generating output :-

```
Attachments, A, B, C, D are missing.
```

How can I avoid first comma after word "`Attachments`" ? Please help.

Other techniques to satisfy the requirement would also be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the [undocumented/unsupported way of concatenating strings](https://sqlblog.org/2011/03/08/t-sql-tuesday-16-this-is-not-the-aggregate-youre-looking-for), use `FOR XML PATH` instead:

```
DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS Message
    UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS Message
    UNION
    SELECT 'C' AS Message
    UNION
    SELECT 'D' AS Message
)

SELECT @msg = 'Attachments ' + 
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + Message 
        FROM CTE
        ORDER BY Message
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    , 1, 2, ' ')

SELECT @msg + ' are missing.'
```

Comment: Will go with this one considering performance. Though I dint understood it enough :( +1

Comment: And for what " TYPE).value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') " is there ? Strange, I dint used data type in select code !!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT @msg = ISNULL(@msg + ', ', 'Attachements ') +  Message FROM CTE
```

and check out `FOR XML` approach for concatenating string

Comment: Thanks for making it simple. +1 for the simplicity :)

Answer (score 1):

use case when

```
SELECT @msg = case when @msg is NULL then 'Attachment ' 
else
COALESCE(@msg + ', ','') 
end
+ Message FROM CTE
SELECT @msg + ' are missing.'
```

Comment: I dint thought about including CASE in my code. :(  thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

Just change the last two lines

```
SELECT @msg = COALESCE(@Msg + ', ','') +  Message FROM CTE

SELECT 'Attachments '+@msg + ' are missing.'
```