# how to remove only comma in the sentence have full of commas

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Data in my table which comes like this

```
Attachements,A,B,C,D.
```

I just want make this

```
Attachements:A,B,C,D.
```

I have tried all the Left,right,LTRIM,RTRIM and Replace functions. this not to deal with spaces

Comment: Is it _always_ the first comma?

Comment: Is it always the first one?  Is it always after the word Attachements?

Comment: `REPLACE(column, 'Attachements,', 'Attachements:')`?

Comment: yes always @DStanley just want to replace first comma

Comment: no use of replace at  Attachements will not be same @jarlh

Comment: Perhaps you could add some more sample data, with variation.

Comment: Just the same questions with 'Attachments:' prefix was today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594403/appending-messages-in-a-variable-using-coalesce-function/35594483#35594483 You should collaborate in your project team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace the first comma you can use:

```
DECLARE @str VARcHAR(100) = 'Attachements,A,B,C,D'

SELECT STUFF(@str, CHARINDEX(',', @str), 1, ':')
```